# How to write changes to ".ini" file using POCO libraries?

Tags: c++, ini, poco-libraries

I'm trying to make changes to a ".ini" file using Poco::Util::IniFileConfiguration. I have the following example *ini* file:

```
[Test]
IP = 192.168.1.1
```

I want to be able to write a new IP to the file. What I have so far is:

```
#include "Poco/Util/IniFileConfiguration.h"
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Util::IniFileConfiguration> pConf( new Poco::Util::IniFileConfiguration( "file.ini" ) );
  if ( pConf->has( "Test.IP" ) ) {
    try {
      std::cout << pConf->getString( "Test.IP" ) << std::endl;
      pConf->setString( "Test.IP", "127.0.0.1" );
      std::cout << pConf->getString( "Test.IP" ) << std::endl;
      // TODO Make changes permanent; write to file!
    } catch ( Poco::SyntaxException& e ) {
      std::cerr << "writeValue: " << e.displayText() << std::endl;
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This code prints the following:

```
192.168.1.1
127.0.0.1
```

The IP is changed on runtime but it doesn't write the changes to disk (file.ini is not changed). Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was strange but currently Poco IniConfigurationFile is readonly and can't be save. [Proof on this presentation](http://pocoproject.org/slides/180-Configuration.pdf).

So, if you want to work with ini files you need to write own implementation to save PocoIniConfiguration or use another library.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I thought; I'll have to look for another library then, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
class CIniConfig : public Poco::Util::IniFileConfiguration
{
//  using namespace Poco::Util;
public :
    CIniConfig();
    using Poco::Util::IniFileConfiguration::IniFileConfiguration;

bool SaveConfig()
{
std::string key ;
    Keys range ;
    //If an empty key is passed, all root level keys are returned.
    enumerate(key,range);
    if(range.empty())
        return false ;
    using namespace std ;
    std::wofstream out;
    out.open(L"config.ini",std::ios_base::out|std::ios_base::trunc);
    if(!out.is_open())
        return false;
    for(auto item : range)
    {

        string pair = item ;
        pair.append("=");
        pair.append(getString(item));
        std::wstring result(pair.begin(),pair.end());
        out << result << endl;
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    return true;
}
}
```